# Creating a mysqlpump with user credentials need help to know the correct syntax

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Recently i ask about using roles in MySQL 8.0 using aurora 3.0 in a Serverless 2 RDS cluster.

They answered me that the correct way to do that is using mysqlpump with the --users parameters to dump all that is stored in the mysql grant users db.

But i dont understand the next statement that i read when i read the official documentation of mysqlpump...

By default, mysqlpump does not dump user account definitions, even if you dump the mysql system database that contains the grant tables. To dump grant table contents as logical definitions in the form of CREATE USER and GRANT statements, use the --users option and suppress all database dumping: mysqlpump --exclude-databases=% --users

My question is...

I want to dump the users that currently are in "testdb" and in this cluster are several dbs like "options1","testdb2","testdb3".

How will be the correct syntax to apply so i can get the users that only affect "testdb" and get the dump of that database too?

I hope you can understand me...

Thanks in advance!